# Overlay на картинку, чтобы он не перекрывал текст

Tags: html, css, scss

Господа, добавил код, при запуске которого можно заметить, что есть overlay, НО, он перекрывает текст. Как сделать так, чтобы оверлей перекрывал только! картинку, и был под текстом (он меняет цвет текста, если текст ссылка - невозможно нажать и тд). Какие есть варианты?

```css
.right-column {
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: flex;
        background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    }   
  .top-content{
    height: 270px;
    background-image: url('https://img2.akspic.ru/previews/9/0/9/8/6/168909/168909-ballonchik-graffiti-ulichnoe_iskusstvo-svet-purpur-500x.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    
}
.top-content::before{
    content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="right-column">
                    <div class="top-content" >
                        <div class="text-top-content">
<h3>26</h3>
<h3>02.12.2015</h3>
<h4>КАК СФОТОГРАФИРОВАТЬ СЕБЯ НА ТЕЛЕФОН ВМЕСТЕ С ЗЕРКАЛКОЙ?</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-content"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Ваш оверлей как background подложку для текста и растяните этот текст на всю картинку, тогда картинка bakground родительского элемента будет затемняться подложкой дочернего, а содержимое дочернего не будет перекрываться:

```css
.text-top-content{
        background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Это хорошая мысль, но она не подойдёт в силу того, что не смогу её адекватно анимировать при помощи hover

Comment: по умолчанию у класса opacity: 0, при hover opacity 1.

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
.right-column {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.top-content {
  height: 270px;
  background-image: url('https://img2.akspic.ru/previews/9/0/9/8/6/168909/168909-ballonchik-graffiti-ulichnoe_iskusstvo-svet-purpur-500x.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-top-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-column">
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="text-top-content">
      <h3>26</h3>
      <h3>02.12.2015</h3>
      <h4>КАК СФОТОГРАФИРОВАТЬ СЕБЯ НА ТЕЛЕФОН ВМЕСТЕ С ЗЕРКАЛКОЙ?</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер! При индексе "-1", псевдокласс проваливается под картинку, во-вторых, нежелательно использовать в коде минусовой индекс.

Comment: Я нашёл решение, оно простое) Тоже задать тексту абсолют) Тогда всё работает

Comment: @Hedonist, а почему не желательно использовать `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.left-column {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.left-top-side {

    background-image: url('https://img2.akspic.ru/previews/9/0/9/8/6/168909/168909-ballonchik-graffiti-ulichnoe_iskusstvo-svet-purpur-500x.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 360px;

}

.nOverlay {}

.left-bottom-side {}

.right-column {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 0;

}

.right-top-side {
    position: relative;

    .right-top-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #fff;

        a {
            color: #fff;
        }
    }

    .nOverlay {
        height: 240px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        display: block;

        &::before {
            content: '';
            width: 94.5%;
            background-color: $dark;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 50%;
            transition: opacity .25s ease;
            
        }


    }
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.right-bottom-side {


    .right-bottom-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 0;

        a {
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
    .nOverlay {
        height: 240px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        display: block;

        &::before {
            content: '';
            width: 94.5%;

            background-color: $dark;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 50%;
            transition: opacity .25s ease;
            
        }


    }
    
}



.nOverlay:hover {
    &::before {
        opacity: 75%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div class="left-top-side">
                        <div class="nOverlay" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="left-bottom-side">
                        <h3>26</h3>
                        <h3>20.12.2022</h3>
                        <h2>Сегодня наш гость расскажет о том, что ждёт новоиспечённых обладателей квадрокоптера</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">

                    <div class="right-top-side">

                        <div class="nPattern">
                            <div class="nOverlay" style="background: url(https://img2.akspic.ru/previews/9/0/9/8/6/168909/168909-ballonchik-graffiti-ulichnoe_iskusstvo-svet-purpur-500x.jpg) no-repeat">
                                <div class="right-top-content">
                                    
                                    
                                    <h3>26</h3>
                                    <h3>20.12.2022</h3>
                                </div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-bottom-side">

                        <div class="nPattern">
                            <div class="nOverlay" style="background: url(https://img2.akspic.ru/previews/9/0/9/8/6/168909/168909-ballonchik-graffiti-ulichnoe_iskusstvo-svet-purpur-500x.jpg) no-repeat">
                                <div class="right-bottom-content">
                                    
                                    <h2>Сегодня наш гость расскажет о том, что ждёт новоиспечённых обладателей квадрокоптера</h2>
                                    <h3>26</h3>
                                    <h3>20.12.2022</h3>
                                </div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Не очень хорошо видно, НО, опасити работает, ховер работает (но не тут) и текст не перекрывается